# Flutter ListTile missing a required argument

Tags: flutter

I'm writing a simple Flutter app that contains a ListView. Following tutorials, my ListView is using a builder, like so:

```
ListView myListItems() {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: count,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
      return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 2.0,
         child: ListTile( // error shows up here
           leading: const Icon(Icons.event_seat),
           title: const Text('Here is some text'),
         )
      );
    },
  );
}
```

...but the line that says,

> "child: ListTile(" has an error on the parenthesis that says, "1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.dart(not_enough_required_arguments)"

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a corrupted Flutter SDK because your code are correct.

Try running this command in your Flutter SDK folder:

```html
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Comment: I ran that, and now I have red squigglies all over the place!

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding. If still persists, try a clean installation of Flutter SDK.

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that in VS Code?

Comment: Flutter clean, build.Wait, where did you run the above commands? In your Flutter Project folder?

Comment: From Powershell in VS Code. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Nah, it's okay. You have to run the above code in the Flutter SDK folder (remember the first time when you setup Flutter. the .zip file you downloaded from flutter.io).  Or to save the hassle, just delete the content inside and replace it with new one downloaded from flutter.io.